# Doxygen RTF disable Index (at end of document)?

Tags: configuration, doxygen

Using doxygen 1.8.4 on Ubuntu 12.04
Generating for C/C++ source into an RTF file.

I'd like to disable the generation of the Index at the end of the document.

There are many hits for DISABLE_INDEX but this is the index at the top of HTML pages, not the main index at the end of the file. I've also searched the documentation for configuration for "index" and none of the hits seem to be about that particular index.

Update: This is also set to NO:

```
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = NO
```

I looked in the DoxygenLayout file and there doesn't seem to be anything specific about the Index section. There are sub-indexes for namespaces, classes, and files. But nothing that I can see for the Index section. I'm not even sure if the DoxygenLayout file is used for RTF files, because of this comment:

```
 <!-- Navigation index tabs for HTML output -->
```

Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated!

TIA
John

Comment: This might be helpful to someone else.  I was searching for an answer to this exact question.  Some aspects of the DoxygenLayout.xml file do apply to RTF, which you also asked about.  For instance, under the <class> node you can hide some things.  I forgot how the brief / detail works and I ended up with a document with duplication of the class summary as both the brief and the detailed description.  I simply togged <briefdescription visible="no"/> so that it is now which did affect the .rft.  Unfortunately it is still not possible to remove the indexes so far as I can tell.

Comment: Changing that setting in the layout was much easier than changing 50 class descriptions to separate the brief and detail summary manually.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well this isn't an answer for this exact post. But it does indicate how to disable the generation of indexes and table of contents for Latex/PDFs.

1. set GENERATE_LATEX=YES and MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME = echo
2. run doxygen to generate the latex file refman.tex
3. cd into the output directory named in LATEX_OUTPUT (typically "latex")
4. copy the Makefile to another directory and edit it:

   - remove all calls to "pdflatex refman" except the first
   - remove the loop
   - remove all calls to "echo refnam.idx"
5. It will look something like:

   ```
   all: refman.pdf
   pdf: refman.pdf
   refman.pdf: clean refman.tex
        pdflatex refman
   clean:
        rm -f *.ps *.dvi *.aux *.toc *.idx *.ind *.ilg *.log *.out *.brf *.blg *.bbl refman.pdf
   ```
6. cd into the output directory again and invoke the modified Makefile

   ```
   cd latex
   make -f ../../doc/Makefile
   ```
7. take a look at refman.pdf. The Table of Contents is gone, the Index is gone.

Caveat: So this works in latex output but does not work for RTF.

For my project, I've converted back to using latex, and so is a solution for me...